# Why is it wrong to put break as an expression in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list, list-comprehension

I tried to write a program to keep asking for an integer input and append it in a list

until 0 is given, in which case I need to print the list that has been created so far and stop the program.

```
list1 = []
while True:
    n = int(input('enter number: '))
    [list1.append(n) if n!=0 else break]
print(list1)
```

This gives me a `SyntaxError`.
**Why is that?**

(I know I can do this without list comprehension but I'm just trying to understand why this is wrong.)

Please excuse any mistakes in my question as it is my first post

Edit: thank you everyone for your explanations. Now I have understood the reason for the error very well.

Comment: `[list1.append(n) if n!=0 else break]` is not a valid list comprehension.

Comment: `break` is not an expression.

Comment: In short, because 'break' is not an expression, it's a statement.

Comment: (Even if `break` *was* an expression, `[list1.append(n) if n!=0 else break]` wouldn't be a valid list comprehension, though. It would be a conditional expression wrapped in an unnecessary 1-element list literal.)

Comment: Right, you're missing the `for` part of the list comprehension. And you'd need the `input()` call to be inside the list comprehension as well.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use an `if` statement, not a conditional expression. The parameters in a conditional expression can only be expressions, not statements like `break`.

There's also no need to put the conditional inside a list.

```
while True:
    n = int(input('enter number: '))
    if n == 0:
        break
    else:
        list1.append(n)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not one of the lines you want to save by using a ternary operator or whatever-comprehension. Just expand it:

```py
while True:
    n = int(input('enter number: '))
    if n == 0:
        break
    list1.append(n)
```

The reason why you can't do it has been given in the comments: `break` is not a valid expression you can use in whatever-comprehensions or the ternary operator. Plus, you risk actually making the code less readable.

Answer (score 0):

## A list comprehension is NOT for one liners.

Its wrong because you're not comprehending a list, you're using it as a one line if statement. The break is not the only problem here, you're also appending to the list inside that "comprehension", not iterating over anything and then not assigning the comprehension result either.

What you've created is a list with a single element in it, which will be at best `[None]` since that is what append returns, but the break is a logical operator, not a value.

Instead, use an actual if statement and multiple readable lines

Answer (score -2):

> The break **statement**, like in C, breaks out of the innermost enclosing for or while loop.

From the [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html?highlight=break#break-and-continue-statements-and-else-clauses-on-loops)

And if you take a look at the [list display BNF notation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html?highlight=comprehension%20bnf#list-displays), you will see, that it expects an expression, and not a statement.

Comment: It *is* in a `while`, though.

Comment: Hm :) You are right. For me it is in a list comprehension. I will edit :)

Comment: It's not in a list comprehension, just a plain list.

Comment: OK, I need a coffee, it is obvious :)